# SQL INSERT INTO - What is wrong here?

Tags: sql, insert

```
INSERT INTO `assets` (SKU, Quantity, Description, Value, Location, Owner, Notes, Index)
VALUES ('OUOUOuouOUO', 'OU', 'OUO', 'IU', 'OI', 'OI', 'HJO', '')
```

Where have I gone wrong in this SQL query? Everything seems to be in order! If it is some thing to do with the choice of quotes i.e. `` ' vs. ` vs. " `` could you explain the usage and choice between them?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: Why do you have to have those '?

Comment: The error is just a syntax error.

Comment: @Fergus Barker: Which database you are using ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SO's syntax highlighting hints at the problem in this query. You need to write the word `Index` in quotes — it is a reserved word, and by using it in this context without quoting I'm guessing your SQL server is getting confused.

```
INSERT INTO `assets`
    (SKU, Quantity, Description, Value, Location, Owner, Notes, `Index`) 
    VALUES ('OUOUOuouOUO', 'OU', 'OUO', 'IU', 'OI', 'OI', 'HJO', '')
```

For more information:

- [MySQL reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)
- [PostgreSQL reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)
- [SQL Server reserved words](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)
- [SQLite reserved words](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)
- [even more..](http://drupal.org/node/141051)

Comment: Alternatively,INSERT INTO `assets`
        (SKU, Quantity, Description, Value, Location, Owner, Notes, [Index]) 
    VALUES ('OUOUOuouOUO', 'OU', 'OUO', 'IU', 'OI', 'OI', 'HJO', '')

Comment: Can you post the error you're seeing when running this query?

Answer (score 0):

Is `Index` a primary key/auto increment value as the name suggests?

If it is, what you're doing is assigning it 0 as a value everytime you do an insert - which obviously you can't, since no two primary key values can be the same.

Solution:

- Assign the index column the `auto_increment` attribute;
- Don't specify the value of `Index` when doing inserts.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the table is also is written in ` this is wrong. please write it without any quotes.

```
INSERT INTO assets (SKU, Quantity, Description, Value, Location, Owner, Notes, Index)
            VALUES ('OUOUOuouOUO', 'OU', 'OUO', 'IU', 'OI', 'OI', 'HJO', '')
```